# video driver Dell Poweredge T110II on board video

Tags: drivers, server, video

I have a couple of Dell Poweredge T110II lite servers.

When I tried installing 18.04.4LTS, the video output would not match the screen - words off the screen, above, below and off the left side of the screen.  No adjustment on the monitor could correct this.

I happened to have a small video card out of a Dell OptiPlex (ATI HD 2400 XT or HD 3450 depending on what website you look at) that I installed and it cleared up the video so it was usable.  I was talking to someone about this and I was told that it is possibly a Matrox G200eW w/8MB memory (onboard) and that Linux sometimes doesn't properly identify it and install the right driver for it.  I think I found the right driver for it but how do I install it?  I found what I think is a driver here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man4/mga.4.html

The file that I downloaded is MGA.4.GZ.  I would like to remove the ATI HD3450 video card and just run it off the embedded video.  At one point I had a gui installed but something got messed up and I ended up reformatting and reistalling the OS so I am trying to go off the command line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to install the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server system?  as many servers do not meet the video minimum requirements [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements] for install of a Desktop system (unless it's a light *flavor* which are now all EOL for 18.04).  The minimums apply to Ubuntu 17.10 & higher (thus include 18.04).

Comment: FYI:  18.04.4 media is rather dated; you should be using [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) media as you're using an outdated/deprecated stack on 18.04.4 (*though it will upgrade to a supported stack*) and it's missing some fixed features included in later ISOs.  The `man` page you reference refers to an EOL release of Ubuntu.

Comment: I did the original install almost 2 years ago, January of 2020, the server has not been running because I was not able to get the raid 5 online.  I have since had someone local help me figure out how to partition it and format it and test it.  Fdisk only was able to partition it to 2Tb so that is going to have to be redone but at least know I know that it is accessible. I have downloaded the latest 18.04.6.  The server is not connected to the outside world so would I have to reinstall from the disc to get it up to 18.04.6?